# What is the most efficient approach to pulling data (using Vue) from a SP list to then export it to Excel?

Tags: list, excel, export, json

I've run across many descriptions on how to effectively/efficiently set up a click event that pulls data from a single SharePoint list and then exports the data to Excel in a Vue.js environment.

So far, I've installed 'vue-excel-export' and 'vue-excel-xlsx' to get things rolling. Using a method that already pulls the data, my question is whether or not to create an array of the data first and then export or build a list of JSON objects and then export the data to Excel?

Any suggestions would really be helpful/appreciated....thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays are more memory efficient than objects, so the data takes less memory.

Reference: https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/i/optimizing-javascript-by-using-arrays-instead-of-objects.html